# permission denied trying to uninstall alfresco

Tags: permissions, alfresco, file-permissions, alfresco-share

I'm trying to uninstall alfresco community so I can reinstall it.
  When I try running (as root)

```
./uninstall
```

I get sudo:

```
unable to execute ./uninstall: Permission denied
```

The reason I'm trying to uninstall it is because I'm getting a permission denied error when trying to start the service:

```
sudo service alfresco start
/etc/init.d/alfresco: line 10: /opt/alfresco-community/alfresco.sh: Permission denied
```

Since getting these errors, I've tried changing the permissions to 777 recursively, but that isn't changing anything.

Any ideas on how I can uninstall alfresco and start over?

Comment: What happens if you run `sh ./uninstall` ? And can you post the output of `ls -l` on the uninstall and alfresco scripts?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  When I try: 
sh ./uninstall, I get 
./uninstall: ./uninstall: cannot execute binary file

Here's what I get for ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user root 5735030 Jul  5 14:42 uninstall
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user root 38901 Jul  5 14:42 alfresco.sh